# creating a list of clickable elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a bar for social media icons that looks like this

[image]

But I'm really stuck.

I tried creating it like this:

```
<div class="social-media">
<ul>
    <li class="facebook">facebook</li>
    <li class="instagram">instagram</li>
    <li class="twitter">twitter</li>
    <li class="youtube">youtube</li>
</ul>
</div>

.social-media ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

.social-media ul li.facebook:after {
content: url('../images/facebooklogo.png');
width: 21px;
height: 21px;
}
```

And so on for each li.class

But the issue was that the images ignored the width and height I specified here, and were huge. I just couldnt seem to target them

The second thing is, I didnt know how to make them whole thing clickable, when I tried using an "a" tag, it didnt target the image specified by the li:after, only the text inside the li

Am I just going about this the wrong way? is it better to use a bunch of nested divs, and use onclick to make the whole thing a link?

Any help would be great, I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a link clickable with a pseudo element? It will put the link after or before it anyway and not on the specified list item.

Comment: Can you put all your code into jsFiddle, please?

Comment: eso es <a href="facebook.com"> <img/> </ a> you can put this in your <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 
`<li><a class="facebook" href="thisIsYourFacebookPage.html">My Facebook page</a></li>`

And give the image you want with

```
a.facebook:before { 
background: url("to/the/path/to/my/image");
width: 21px;
height: 21px;
display: inline-block;
content: " ";
}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gVp2P/1/

Comment: thanks for that, i still cant get it to work, but i will keep at it. the width and height dont affect the size of the image? just the size of the box in which the image is displayed though?

Comment: sorry, just to let anyone reading know, this answer did work perfectly, and i adjusted the image size by adding this : background-size: 21px 21px;

Comment: Good to hear mate. Please mark the answer as "answered" so we can close off this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specific a url for content, as far as I know. But you don't need to use pseudo elements here. Just specific the background-image of each `<li>`

```
.social-media ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
}
.social-media ul li.facebook {
    background-image: url('../images/facebooklogo.png');
}
```

If you want them to be clickable links, you really don't even need the `ul li`. Just use `<a>` directly, give it a class, facebook, linkedin, etc, then the following CSS.

```
.social-media a {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
}
.social-media a.facebook {
    background-image: url('../images/facebooklogo.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider the icons as font's instead of images.

The reason is they scale better, lookin really nice even if your users zoom or use retina displays, and you can just add css colors, shadows and so on just as you would do styling your text.

read on here: 
http://icomoon.io/